# How to declare a variable as a time value and add to it

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to make one of my variable an initial starting time and have the output be an addition to that time based on a number of parameters.

For instance;

I start subtract x from y and get z. Then I take z and divide it from x getting the % of that difference to the original number. Then based on that percentage every 5% represents 5mins. So if i start at 10:00am and the price of hotdog is $10 and if drops to $8 (20% drop) I want to show a 20min addition to 10:00am.

My issue is that when I get to the addition to the original time it goes past 60 min. So instead of it going from 900 to 1010 it goes to 970.

How do I make it count from 60’s like time. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code.

Comment: Use a **[`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** object

Comment: Store everything as minutes (or seconds) and convert the values whenever needed.

Answer (score 1):

Store everything as minutes (or seconds, days - whatever is most suitable) and convert the values whenever needed:

```
function convertToHourString (minutes) {
    return Math.floor( minutes / 60 ) + ':' + minutes % 60
}

convertToHourString(10); // 0:10
convertToHourString(70); // 1:10
```